# could Not create laravel_logger_activity_table

Tags: laravel-7

I try to install the `jeremykenedy/laravel-logger` this packaged but am get this error

[image]

how can i resolve this  problem

Comment: All I can see is that you ran a migration file using php artisan migrate. I don't see that you tried to install any package from the screenshot above. What is inside the 2017....activity_table?

Comment: @OConnor, I just followup this step
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-logger

this table does not created in migration

Comment: I just install a new Laravel 8 and followed that guide. I install laravel-logged using composer, everything works fine, the laravel_logger_activity db table is created as well. What is your laravel version and how did you install that laravel-logged package?

Comment: Im using  `"laravel/framework": "^7.0"` and i followup the steps as well